# Curious badge SQL

Tags: support

Is there a curious badge SQL check? Similar to [unsung hero](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121674/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement)?

I found [different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge) [explanations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15164/meaning-of-curious-badge), but not the full SQL to find what is missing.

[This SQL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record) just give me the rate, but it doesn't return eligible questions. It returns I have 24 questions, one negative and asking record 0.958333, but not why only four questions are considered "well received" while I count five questions with votes > 0 asked on different days.

[This SQL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges) (marked this question as duplicate) returns that I have six questions, and I'm qualified to the Curious badge although I'm not, in my page only four questions are considered for this badge.

I found that I have a deleted question with -1 vote in the same day I have a question with +1 vote, so I'm suspecting the SQL contains votes sum per day > 0.

Comment: This still doesn't keep full SQL, It doesn't get number of question elligible

Comment: I didn't see any SQL also there

Comment: You don't need SQL just count up, you've not that many questions. Remember to include deleted ones though.

Comment: I count 5 questions with votes > 0 asked in different days

Comment: I have deleted question with -1 vote in the same day I vote +1 for diferent question. This is probably the issue

Comment: I use http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges, but the SEDE doesn't have your deleted questions so it can't ever be accurate.

Comment: You have 11 deleted questions, one of which is closed, 9 of which have a score < 0. That makes a total of 35 questions, and your ratio is (35 - 10 - 1 - 11) / 35 == 13 / 35 == 0.37, which is below 0.5. You'd need a straight 9 additional questions that are not downvoted, not closed *and* not deleted to get that ratio to 0.5.

Comment: I didn't realize it included deleted questions. Does it mean only questions that moderators or the community deleted, or does it include ones he deleted himself?

Comment: The SQL in duplicate returns that I have 6 questions and I'm qualified to Curious Badge although I'm not https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges

Comment: @SandPiper all deleted questions count no matter how they are deleted.

Comment: @user7294900 as Martijn said, SQL can't return deleted questions.